# xcode osx webview new window

Tags: webview, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with webview.

I made a simple webbrowser for Osx, within I have to hide nvigation bar , menu amd right click and the user can go only in one specific url..

all this is ok but I need that allow _blank target.. i mean .. I have some link woth target _blank, so to open in a new window, but it does no work and i don't know hot to allow this.

this is my code for DataOAppDelegate.h:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface DataOAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSWindowDelegate>
{WebView *WebView;

    //other instance variable
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;



@end
```

and code for DataOAppDelegate.m

```
#import "DataOAppDelegate.h"
//#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@implementation DataOAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize myWebView;

//your function etc



-(void)awakeFromNib{

    NSString *urlText = @"http://website.com";
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    [myWebView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [window setDelegate:self];
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [myWebView setUIDelegate:self];
    NSString *urlText = @"http://website.com";
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
}


- (WebView *)myWebView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"sss%@",sender);
    NSUInteger windowStyleMask =    NSClosableWindowMask |
    NSMiniaturizableWindowMask |
    NSResizableWindowMask |
    NSTitledWindowMask;
    NSWindow* webWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 600) styleMask:windowStyleMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    WebView* newWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:[webWindow contentRectForFrameRect:webWindow.frame]];
    [newWebView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [webWindow setContentView:newWebView];
    [webWindow center];
    [webWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [[newWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
    return newWebView;
}

- (void)launchSoftWithBundleID:(NSString *)softPath
{
    NSBundle *softBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:softPath];
    NSString *bundleID = [softBundle bundleIdentifier];
    //
    NSTask *softTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [softTask setLaunchPath:softPath];
    [softTask launch];
    //
    NSArray *array = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:bundleID];
    if ([array count] > 0)
    {
        NSRunningApplication *runningApp = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        [runningApp activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WebViews have delegate methods to do so: `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` and `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)).

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id)listener {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.YourVebView]) {
        [listener use];
    }
    else {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey]];
        [listener ignore];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey]];
    [listener ignore];
}
```

Note: don't forget to set the policy delegate for your WebView.